# Cast to string failed for value \"{ details: '233' }\" at path \"setno\" for model \"Trains\

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, express-graphql

I have been trying to see and Resolve it but ended up with no relevant solution all over.
Need More Inputs and Suggestions to solve this Issue. Please Check My Below Code Details.
I am Using Express GraphQL,and mongoose version :^5.9.25

I am Using GraphQL to Do that,

> ***Below is My Query Request***

```
query {
  getTrainsbySetno(details:"233"){
  _id
  setno
  train_no
  start_station_code
  end_station_code
  route_code
  train_type
  start_on
  change_on
  halts_at
  createdAt
  updatedAt
 }
}
```

> ***My GraphqL Query Response***

```
{
  "errors": [
  {
  "message": "Cast to string failed for value \"{ details: '233' }\" at path \"setno\" for model \"Trains\"",
  "locations": [
    {
      "line": 55,
      "column": 3
    }
  ],
  "path": [
    "getTrainsbySetno"
  ]
}
],
"data": {
 "getTrainsbySetno": null
 }
}
```

> ***Below is My Resolver***

```
getTrainsbySetno: async (details) => {
     
    try {
        const result = await Trains.find({$or:[{setno: details },{train_no: details}]});
        console.log(result);
        return result.map(res => {
           
            return { ...res._doc, _id: res.id };
            
        });            
    } catch (err) {
        
        throw err;
    }
   
},
```

> ***Below is My Schema:***

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const trainsSchema = new Schema ({

        setno : {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        train_no : {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        start_station_code : {
            type: String,
            required: false
        },
        end_station_code : {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        route_code : {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        train_type : {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        start_on : {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        change_on : {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        halts_at : {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
  
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Trains', trainsSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the getTrainsbySetno method, the parameter "details" is an object. So to get the value of the details obj we need to replace details with "details.details" .

Comment: Yes, I forgot To Consider Details as an object